# Почему конвертер срабатывает только один раз?

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу в Text  КомбоБокса выводить строку с именами всех отмеченных объектов класса Person. Прибиндил, создал конвертер. Конвертер срабатывает только при инициализации, а при изменении/добавлении/удалении элементов не срабатывает. Как это побороть?
XAML:

```
 <Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyConverter
        x:Key="conv" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="150" Height="25"
            x:Name="SearchFilterCorpseDeathPlace"   
            IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
            IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"
            IsEditable="True"                                      
            SelectedValuePath="Name"
            TextSearch.TextPath="Name"                                                                
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Person}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Person.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
            Foreground="Black" 
            Text="{Binding Path=Persons, Converter={StaticResource conv}}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox 
                        x:Name="SearchFilterCorpseDeathPlaceCheckBox"
                        Content="{Binding Name}" 
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" >
                    </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Viewmodel:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        private bool _ischecked;
        public bool IsChecked { get { return _ischecked; } set { _ischecked = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Person> _person;
        public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get { return _person; } set { _person = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>() {
                new Person(){Name="Ivan", Age=28, IsChecked=false},
                new Person(){Name="Egor", Age=28, IsChecked=false},
                new Person(){Name="Stas", Age=28, IsChecked=false},
                new Person(){Name="Igor", Age=28, IsChecked=false}

            };
        }

    }
```

Converter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WPFTest
{
    public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            string result = null;

            var collection = (IEnumerable<Person>)value;

            foreach (Person p in collection)
            {
                if (p.IsChecked)
                {

                    if (result == null)
                    {
                        result = p.Name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = result + string.Format("," + "p.Name");
                    }
                }
            }




            return result;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код не работает потому, что конвертер и вообще обновление привязки происходит при изменении самого свойства `Persons`, а не свойств подобъектов. А свойство `Persons` при отметке отдельных элементов не меняется.

---

Например, вы можете сделать так:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox 
        Content="{Binding Name}" 
        IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
        Checked="OnCheckChanged"
        Unchecked="OnCheckChanged">
    </CheckBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

```
void OnCheckChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var combobox = SearchFilterCorpseDeathPlace;
    var persons = (IEnumerable<Person>)combobox.DataContext;
    combobox.Text = string.Join(", ", persons.Where(p => p.IsChecked).Select(p => p.Name));
}
```

Comment: Это известно. Как побороть?

Comment: @Ghsee: В вопросе вы не указали, что вам известна причина :)

Comment: Спасибо за решение, но оно не подходит. Сперва сделал аналогично, но сказали что это костыли и не по MVVM, таких комбобоксов около 100 штук. Пробовал из Nuget  пакет ObservableCollectionEx, по описанию там вызывается CollectionChanged  на каждый ItemChanged  в коллекции, но WPF  не понимает этого

Comment: @Ghsee: Почему это вдруг не по MVVM? Список, разделённый запятыми — ваше визуальное состояние, к VM не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: @Ghsee: А вот если таких комбобоксов сто штук, поместите тогда код в UserControl.